# How to use MS Windows Dialogs in JSF 1.2 without using Java Script or Tomahawk framework?

Tags: jsf, file-upload

Is it possible by using JSF 1.2 to work with the dialogs, which will allocate by Microsoft Windows (or an another operation system) to choose a file for example? A File Upload and Download is also important for me. Is it necessary to use the Tomahawk framework to implement this requirement?

Comment: You could just use regular html/javascript. `alert('Hello world')` will trigger a browser dependent dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is strange. You're basically thinking in the wrong direction. Whatever you want is a HTML `<input type="file">` whose value can be bound to a JSF backing bean property. The operating system used by the client is completely irrelevant.

One way, as you apparently already figured, is using Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>`. Until version 2.2, JSF doesn't have a file upload component in the standard component set. Tomahawk's one has in years proven to be the best choice for a JSF file upload component in standard look'n'feel. Your aversion against using it isn't making any sense. Perhaps you tried it once and failed and then gave up, incorrectly blaming the library instead of yourself. [This blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html) contains a clear set of instructions how to install and use it.